# How to check that current time is between working hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

I need to check if the current time is between a representative's work hours (not with external library as  momentJS).

What I have:

```
localTimeZone = 'America/New_York';
localWorkingHours = [
  {day: 'Sunday', from: '08:00', to: '14:00'},
  {day: 'Sunday', from: '23:00', to: '23:59'},
  {day: 'Monday', from: '00:00', to: '07:00'},
  {day: 'Tuesday', from: '08:00', to: '16:00'},
  {day: 'Wednesday', from: '08:00', to: '16:00'}
];

const now = new Date();
const currentDayInWeek = now.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: localTimeZone,
    weekday: 'long'
});
const workingTimes = localWorkingHours.filter(times => times.day === currentDayInWeek);
workingTimes.forEach((time) => {
   // what is the best option to check that current time is between time.from and time.to ?
   // note that this code should run in another AWS region.
})
```

Comment: This sort of problem is not *completely impossible* without a library, but you may find it very challenging.  In particular, re-parsing a formatted date string is going to be error prone for sure.  The `Date` object just wasn't designed for this sort of thing. The good news is that the [TC39 Temporal Proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) will eventually bring a full-fledged date and time API into the JavaScript language. There's even [a cookbook example](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html#comparison-of-an-exact-time-to-business-hours) for this exact scenario.

Comment: In the meantime, I'd advise either [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) rather than Moment, due to [Moment's status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I did it very simple without the need to install another library (I don't want it due to security updates), see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
const now = new Date();
const currentDayInWeek = now.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: localTimeZone,
    weekday: 'long'
});
const currentTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], {
    timeZone: localTimeZone,
    hour12: false,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
}).format(now);

const workingTimes = localWorkingHours.filter(times => times.day === currentDayInWeek);

return workingTimes.some((time) => {
    if (currentTime >= time.from && currentTime <= time.to) return true;
});
```

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, and should be OK except I would pass the same `en-US` (or another locale) on *both* parts, as to avoid erroneous errors if the user's locale is something else (since you are comparing strings lexicographically).  Also, I'd recommend using half-open intervals, and you might want to include a check for handling working hours that span over midnight, which together would be: `(time.from <= time.to) ? (currentTime >= time.from && currentTime < time.to) : (currentTime >= time.from || currentTime < time.to)`

Comment: Thanks! about the 'en-US' locale - it's only the **format of the date** (I really can remove it, it has no meaning here), the currentDayInWeek 
 will be for example 'Sunday' according to the timeZone in the options object and not according to locale.

Comment: About working hours that span over midnight, nice solution. What I did - you can see in Sunday hours: from 23:00 to 23:59, and next day Monday from 00:00 to 07:00 to handle it.

Comment: Some locales will present with numbers in other character families.  For example, `'ar-SA'` will give you a time string like `'١٥:١٦'`